# Why is there no error about "Not unique table/alias"

Tags: mysql

SQL like this: (`test_db` has one table `t`, table `t` has one column `id`)

```
USE test_db;
SELECT * FROM t, (SELECT * FROM test_db.t) as t;
```

I think there will be an error here "Not unique table/alias", but it doesn't.
I guess their unique name actually is  `test_db.t` and `t`(no database?)

Now, I want to expand the star to fields, just like:

```
SELECT test_db.t.id, ? FROM t, (SELECT * FROM test_db.t) as t;
```

what should I do?
Or rather, what is the unique name of the derived table?
(When I use `t`, It is actually both `test_db.t` and derived table `t`)

Comment: Use a different alias for one of the tables and you do not have to wonder. (Although this does seem to be a bug to me)

Comment: I feel the the same,